# Django object count is non-zero with no objects following deletions for polymorphic model

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, polymorphism

Can anyone explain how this is possible? Transcript from a django 1.6 `./manage.py shell` session:

```
In [7]: CoatPatternType.objects.all()
Out[7]: []

In [8]: CoatPatternType.objects.all().count()
Out[8]: 12

In [9]: CoatPatternType.objects.count()
Out[9]: 12

In [10]: CoatPatternType.objects.all()[0]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-ed2eaeafe12a> in <module>()
----> 1 CoatPatternType.objects.all()[0]

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.pyc in __getitem__(self, k)
    130         qs = self._clone()
    131         qs.query.set_limits(k, k + 1)
--> 132         return list(qs)[0]
    133
    134     def __and__(self, other):

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Background:

Wanting to clean up some data in my development environment, I:

1. Backed up the database with `pg_dump my_db -F tar -f dbdumps/backup.tar`
2. Dumped out the desired data via `./manage.py dumpdata my_app --natural --indent=4 > fixture.json`
3. Flushed the data via a combination of model deletions and `./manage.py sqlsequencereset my_app | ./manage.py dbshell`.
4. Attempted to restore the dumped data via `./manage.py loaddata fixture.json`.

The last step failed with

```
django.core.serializers.base.DeserializationError: Problem installing fixture 'fixture.json': CoatPatternType matching query does not exist.
```

...leading me to investigate via the afore-mentioned shell session.

There are indeed 12 rows in the relevant CoatPatternType model's table, as verified in psql:

```
my_db=# select id from my_app_coatpatterntype;
 id 
 ----
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  6
  7
  8
  9
 10
 11
 12
(12 rows)
```

CoatPatternType is a django-polymorphic-tree model, if that makes a difference.

Also, if I dumpdata without --natural, the loaddata command succeeds, but I don't want to hard-code PK values in my fixture since it will ultimately be used in other environments.

While researching this issue, I came across this:

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16773

which seems to indicate the problem might be with caching of the count or result set. The relevant last entries from `connections['default'].queries` are:

```
 {u'sql': u'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "my_app_coatpatterntype"',
  u'time': u'0.001'},
 {u'sql': u'SELECT "my_app_coatpatterntype"."id",
  "my_app_coatpatterntype"."polymorphic_ctype_id", 
  "my_app_coatpatterntype"."lft", "my_app_coatpatterntype"."rght", 
  "my_app_coatpatterntype"."tree_id", 
  "my_app_coatpatterntype"."level", 
  "my_app_coatpatterntype"."sort_index", 
  "my_app_coatpatterntype"."parent_id", 
  "my_app_coatpatterntype"."name", 
  FROM "my_app_coatpatterntype" ORDER BY 
  "my_app_coatpatterntype"."tree_id" ASC, 
  "my_app_coatpatterntype"."lft" ASC LIMIT 1',
  u'time': u'0.001'}
```

so django appears to be hitting the database for each query.

So my question is, how can django be reporting a count without finding any objects? And why are the objects not being found in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Ha! Of course, the reference pointed to by the object being reloaded that triggered the DeserializationError (that swallowed the mouse that ate the cheese..) got removed during the clean-up, so that error was accurate and expected.

That doesn't explain how count() can return 12 rows but all() is empty, of course. So if anyone has an idea why that might be, please let me know.